# Why is it that, if there are no odd perfect numbers, then there are no other $3$-perfect numbers, apart from the six known, as of the year $1643$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

A number $N$ is said to be $k$-perfect if $\sigma(N)=kN$ where $k$ is a positive integer.

The number $1$ is $1$-perfect, since $1=\sigma(1)=1\cdot{1}=1$.

If a number $P$ is $2$-perfect, then $P$ can simply be called a *perfect number*.

If a number $T$ is $3$-perfect, then $T$ is called a *triperfect number*.

The following excerpt is taken verbatim from the Introduction of [Cohen and Sorli's paper titled "ON ODD PERFECT NUMBERS AND EVEN 3-PERFECT NUMBERS"](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/a6self/a6self.pdf):

> There are six known $3$-perfect numbers, all found more than $360$ years ago, the
> last in $1643$. They are
> $$120 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5,$$
> $$672 = 2^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 7,$$
> $$523776 = 2^9 \cdot 3 \cdot {11} \cdot {31},$$
> $$459818240 = 2^8 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot {19} \cdot {37} \cdot {73},$$
> $$1476304896 = 2^{13} \cdot 3 \cdot {11} \cdot {43} \cdot {127},$$
> $$51001180160 = 2^{14} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot {19} \cdot {31} \cdot {151}.$$
> At a Western Number Theory Conference some years ago, John Selfridge quickly
> wrote these up by considering even $3$-perfect numbers in the form $2^a M$, $M$ odd,
> and factorizing $2^{a+1} − 1$ for $a \leq 14$; he went on to ask what was known otherwise
> of such numbers. It is generally assumed, for example by Achim Flammenkamp in
> his Multiply Perfect Numbers Page (http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html), that
> there are no others, but this presupposes that no odd perfect numbers exist. This
> is a consequence of the following result; the proof is easy.
>
> > **Lemma 1** An odd number $N$ is perfect if and only if $2N$ is $3$-perfect.

Here then is my question:

> Why is it that, if there are no odd perfect numbers, then there are no other $3$-perfect numbers, apart from the six known, as of the year $1643$?

**MY OWN THOUGHTS**

(I would like to state at the outset that I understand the proof of **Lemma 1**.)

Surely, if the list of six ($6$) even $3$-perfect numbers as given above is complete, and if there are no odd perfect numbers, then there are no other $3$-perfect numbers.

My point is that:  What if the list of six ($6$) even $3$-perfect numbers as given above is incomplete?  Or is the fact that the six ($6$) known *even* $3$-perfect numbers complete the list of even $3$-perfect numbers derivable from known properties of *even* $3$-perfect numbers?

Comment: Lemaa $1$ allows $3-$perfect numbers that are multiples of $4$ or a higher power of $2$, without an odd perfect number.

Comment: @Empy2: Thank you for your time and attention!  Well yes, but that was not my point.  What if the list of six ($6$) even $3$-perfect numbers as given above is incomplete?  (In other words, how is Achim Flammenkamp so sure that the list above is complete, if there are no odd perfect numbers?)

Comment: Do you know a search limit for the $3$-perfect numbers ? In other words, if there is another $3$-perfect number , how large must it be ?

Comment: I don't know his reasons.  He claims there are infinitely many $2-$perfect numbers and I don't think that is known to be true.

Comment: Also, what about odd $3$-perfect numbers ? Can they be ruled out ?

Comment: @Empy2 This is in fact open since it is unknown whether there are infinite many Mersenne primes , it is just conjectured that there are infinite many based on heuristics.

Comment: @Peter:  I do not know the current search limit for the $3$-perfect numbers.

Comment: @Peter: In fact, it is conjectured that there are no odd $k$-perfect numbers apart from $1$.  (See this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/150240/10365) and the references indicated therein.)

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I am aware of this conjecture , but I do not know "how sure" we can be that it is true.